# dotnetcore Mutual Certificate Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

In Asp.net core, how do I enable 2 way certificate authentication to a specific controller?

I found this link
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2016/04/13/azure-web-app-client-certificate-authentication-with-asp-net-core-2/

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an article 
"Introduction to Authentication with ASP.NET Core"
https://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-authentication-with-asp-net-core/

based on which I wrote a Client Certificate Middleware
https://github.com/xavierjohn/ClientCertificateMiddleware

Now available as a nuget package.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/CWiz.ClientCertificateMiddleware/

Comment: What is the difference between this, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1?

Comment: That did not exist in those days and I have not updated mine to support .net core 3.1